# Capybara cannot find date picker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri, capybara

Using capybara, I am trying to fill in a date. There is a javascript date picker on the form. I have tried the following ways to choose it:

```
find('input[type=date]').focus()
find(:xpath, ".//*[@id='Sdate']")
fill_in('Sdate', :with => '25/07/2555')
```

However for all of these attempts, I got the exact same error message:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: '[JavaScript Error: "a is null" {file: "file:///var/folders/ky/r1ft86wd5x9cjq0f3f6tq0600000gn/T/webdriver-profile20120725-41019-m72bh5/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js" line: 5813}]' when calling method: [nsICommandProcessor::execute]
```

The html I am trying to fill in:

```
<input id="Sdate" type="text" readonly="" value="" size="10" name="Sdate">
<img align="absmiddle" onclick="return showCalendar('Sdate', 'dd/mm/yy');" style="cursor:pointer" src="../images/calendar_s.gif">
```

I am using Selenium webdriver on Firefox with Capybara 1.1.2 in a Rails 3.2.6 task.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried doing it without selenium instead? I ask, because if you are doing an integration test that just needs a valid date entered, then is there a reason to try and utilize the date picker? Which is probably already tested based on the library you are using.

Comment: I'm trying to scrape info from a website, so I need to use selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same setup and I was able to select box with this line:

```
select 'May', from: 'date_select_1'
```

where *'May'* is a value which you want select from list and the *data_select_1* is ID of HTML tag from which you want select the value.

Comment: It's not a select list so this does not seem to work. There are no options in the html to choose from.

Comment: Are you sure, that you have correctly set the selenium driver?

Comment: [link](http://railscasts.com/episodes/257-request-specs-and-capybara?view=asciicast) here is more info

Comment: Ok I have it working now. I have to click on the image before the Javascript shows up. But your link helped me think it through, thanks.

Comment: No problem! Good luck with that